# converting values inside nested list into integers except first value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to convert values inside a nested list into integers except for the first value. For example:

```
x = [['a', '1',' 2',' 3', '4',' 5'], ['b', '11',' 12',' 13',' 14',' 15'], ['c', '21',' 22',' 23',' 24', '25']]
```

to this

```
x = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

I tried using

```
w = []
for i in list1:
    for j in i:
        v = list(int(j))
        w.append(v)
```

and

```
for i in file_list:
    j = i[:1] + list(map(int, i[1:]))
```

but I get

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File  
> "/Users/abhishekabhishek/PycharmProjects/normalize/venv/normalize.py",  
> line 63, in <module>  
>     v = list(int(j)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.66171813'
> ```

Comment: Your error message mentions an attempt to parse `'2.66171813'` as an int. Does your example data fully reflect your real data? (e.g. are there decimals/floats?) What does your second attempt (with `list(map(int...))`) output?

Comment: actually its a file with floating point values instead of simple integers that was jus an example list

Comment: Ok, I was confounded at first since the error doesn't match the example given. Are you _sure_ you want to convert the numbers to integers? Floats would seem more appropriate for normalising data (I presume, from the name of your file). As mentioned by Chris in his comments, please provide sample data that fully reflects your real data. Thx.

Comment: yeah I would like to convert them into float

Comment: is there any way by which I can upload my csv file

Answer (score 1):

A more robust way to check if a string can be converted to a number is to actually convert it, but use a `try-except` block to catch exceptions:

```
for i, l in enumerate(x):
    r = []
    for f in l:
        try:
            r.append(float(f))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    x[i] = r
```

so that given:

```
x = [['a', '1.1',' 2',' 3', '4',' 5'], ['b', '11',' 12',' 13',' 14',' 15'], ['c', '21',' 22',' 23',' 24', '25']]
```

`x` would become:

```
[[1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0], [21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `int` directly if your *actual* data contains `float`-like `str`s. Use `float` instead:

```
x = [['a', '1', ' 2.22', ' 3', '4', ' 5'],
 ['b', '11', ' 12', ' 13', ' 14', ' 15'],
 ['c', '21', ' 22', ' 23', ' 24', '25']]

new_list = [list(map(float, s[1:])) for s in x]
print(new_list)
[[1.0, 2.22, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
 [21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0]]
```

In case there can be some empty str `''`:

```
x = [['a', '1', ' 2.22', ' 3', '4', ' 5'],
 ['b', '11', ' ', ' 13', ' 14', ' 15'],
 ['c', '21', ' 22', ' 23', ' 24', '25']]

new_list = [] 
for l in x:
    new_list.append([float(s) if s.strip() else None for s in l[1:]])
print(new_list)
[[1.0, 2.22, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [11.0, None, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
 [21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0]]
```

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
it says this

Comment: @AbhishekAbhishek Can you update your question reflecting your actual data?

Comment: [['Albania','4.639548302','9.373718262','0.637698293','69.05165863','0.74961102',-'0.035140377','0.457737535']
['Algeria','5.248912334','9.540244102','0.806753874','65.69918823','0.436670482',-0.'194670126']]

Comment: and there are hundred more lines these are just two

Comment: I don't know why its working on your but not on mine

Comment: Your example is not a valid object.  There's `-'0.035140377'` which is not a valid `str`. Second list also contains `-0.'194670126'`. Are these from python?

Comment: Read in the CSV formated text file. That is, fields in each row are separated by commas, e.g. 
Albania,4.639548302,9.373718262,0.637698293,69.05165863,0.74961102,-0.035140377,0.457737535
Algeria,5.248912334,9.540244102,0.806753874,65.69918823,0.436670482,-0.194670126,
Apart from the first field, all the other fields are either numbers (so converted using float(), or empty, which can be translated to the Python object None. Each line will be transformed into a row, represented as a list, so you end up with a list of lists.

Comment: could you tell me how can we do that

Comment: I believe this question is no longer about _converting values inside nested list_, which implies there is a valid python object to begin with. IMO, you should make a new question asking about how to parse csv files using python. In the meantime, try using `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: no actually I have to normalize these values using a function I defined  that function and it worked on other nested list by the time could you tell me how I can rows into convert them into float and empty spaces into python object None as the task describes

Comment: I agree that pandas seems better suited here. "a", "b", "c", "Algeria", and "Albania" seem like labels to me. @AbhishekAbhishek what's the _complete_ error message/traceback you get when running Chris' code?

Comment: list2 = [list(map(float, s[1:])) for s in list1]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @AbhishekAbhishek Can you `print(list1[:2])` and show us?

Comment: [['2.66171813', '7.460143566', '0.490880072', '52.33952713', '0.427010864', '-0.106340349', '0.261178523'], ['4.639548302', '9.373718262', '0.637698293', '69.05165863', '0.74961102', '-0.035140377', '0.457737535']]

Comment: @AbhishekAbhishek Take a look at the updated answer.